# Can R 3D plot ticks be coerced to the other side?

Tags: r, plot, 3d

The persp() function seems to dynamically decide which side of a 3D plot to put the tick marks.

For example, in the below picture, the axis labelled Direction 1 and the associated ticks marks appear on the left of the plot. Can they be made to appear on the right of the plot instead **without** changing the perspective?

[image]

(Some of the) associated code used to generate the plot:

```
persp(xs.1, xs.2, z2.res, ,xlab=" Direction 1",
zlim=range(y)+c(-5,5),theta=85, phi=10, expand=.75,
ticktype = "detailed", nticks = 4, cex.lab=.75, cex.axis=.75)->z2.plot
```

Comment: What 3D rendering package are you currently using for this plot? I would recommend the `rgl` package since this can be easily controlled using the `mtext3d` function.

Comment: This is done via the persp() command. So its part of the     graphics package. The problem I was having with     rgl was that it was showing the entire plane in the display window. This particular plot tails off a loooong way down.